# Chrome Developer Tools: What is this "Break on" option present on DOM elements?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was watching a frontend development course. In it, the author just mentioned an option in chrome developer tools "Break on", but didn't explain it.

This break on option appears when we right click a DOM element. Anyone has any idea what's the purpose of it?

I have attached an image for the context.
[image]

Comment: See [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#dom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, **Break on...** let's you pause on the code that changes the DOM node in one of the following ways,

1. **Subtree modifications:**
   Triggered when the child node is added/removed or its contents modified.
2. **Attributes modifications:**
   Triggered when the attribute of the node is added/removed or its value changed.
3. **Node Removal:**
   Triggered when the selected node is removed.

More info:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#dom

[image]